# Rest Template pass original Message

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, resttemplate

I am building a (mostly) pass through API with RestTemplate which queries various different services. On errors and missing parameters the target APIs deliver error messages which go missing in the responses and I want to pass those through with the same HttpCode. Example:

`curl -XPOST sourceapi:/...`

`{"type":"/errors/failed","title":"Entity Exists","details":"Entity  with name \"test\" already exists","status":409}`

If I do the same with a RestTemplate it throws and Exception and the message is null and it looks like this:

`curl -XPOST testapi:/...`

`409 null`

How can I pass error code as well as that object there down to the "client". (even logging it would be a start...)

I got a `@ControllerAdvice` class which already caches it but the message is actually just `409 null`

```
  @ExceptionHandler(value = {HttpClientErrorException.class})
  public ResponseEntity<Object> clientErrorException(HttpClientErrorException ex) {
    return ResponseEntity.status(ex.getStatusCode()).body(ex.getMessage());
  }
```

Is there a way to add an ErrorParser or something while building the Template with RestTemplateBuilder?

Comment: maybe this is the answer you are looking for: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-template-error-handling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't `getResponseBodyAsString()` method (inherited from `RestClientResponseException`) what you seek?

```java
  @ExceptionHandler(value = {HttpClientErrorException.class})
  public ResponseEntity<Object> clientErrorException(HttpClientErrorException ex) {
    return ResponseEntity.status(ex.getStatusCode()).body(ex.getResponseBodyAsString());
  }
```

Or perhaps `getResponseBodyAsByteArray()` would be a better fit.

Comment: It is. Easier then I though thank you very much ;). The String Method is actually JSON parseble so I will go with that.